# How to change text cursor color in Windows?

Tags: windows, accessibility, text-cursor, caret

Is it possible to change text cursor color systemwide? I want to make it easy to catch red color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only option I have found is to use an utility called [Aml Maple](http://amlpages.com/amlmaple.shtml). It colors cursor depending on current keyboard Layout. I set red color to all layouts, so I got what I needed. It does not work in some applications, has monstrous UI, but otherwise does its work pretty well. So I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For most controls the caret doesn't have a "color". It inverts the color of the pixels behind it - white becomes black, blue becomes yellow, etc. Here is a paragraph I found from Windows.

> After the caret is defined, use the ShowCaret function to make the
>   caret visible. When the caret appears, it automatically begins
>   flashing. To display a solid caret, the system inverts every pixel in
>   the rectangle; to display a gray caret, the system inverts every other
>   pixel; to display a bitmap caret, the system inverts only the white
>   bits of the bitmap.

I have never seen an example of someone changing the color, but you can change shape, flashing, width. But if you go into **Control panel -> Ease of Access -> Make the computer easier to see** you can adjust other options. [Guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/194095/how-to-change-the-blinking-windows-keyboard-cursor-thickness/)